# I want my bot to tell you that you must mention someone, when you dont

Tags: python, discord.py

I have bunch of fun commands like "hug, marry etc."

They are working with

.hug user

but ı want my python bot tell "You need to mention someone"  if you dont mention a user. However, whenever I test the bot, nothing happens and users cant know that they need to mention a user

My code:

```
async def hug(ctx,user:discord.Member):
    if not discord.Member:
        await ctx.send("you need to mention someone")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author} hugs {user.name}", description="nice...")
    embed.set_image(url="url")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)``
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What happens when the code is executed? It looks like it would work. Adding all the relevant information can help with providing a useful answer

Comment: Nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple, the message object has a `mentions` attribute, you can check the length of the message's mentions and if they are not equal to 1 then there should be an error.

```py
async def hug(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    if len(ctx.message.mentions) != 1:
        await ctx.send("you must mention a user!")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author} hugs {user.name}", description="nice...")
    embed.set_image(url="url")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)``
```

The Discord API documentation about the `message.mentions attribute`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20mentions#discord.Message.mentions

Answer (score 0):

The way you are checking, is wrong, you defined an attribute named `user` and gave it a type `discord.Member`, so you need to check whether `user` is passed.

```
async def hug(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    if not user:
        await ctx.send("you must mention a user!")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author} hugs {user.name}", description="nice...")
    embed.set_image(url="url")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**The problem, if you are checking** `len(ctx.message.mentions) != 1`, is that when you use:
`.hug xyz @billy` it is also gonna pass the if condition, but not gonna work, instead it will throw an error. because a **BadArgument** - `xyz` is passed second.